# Jenkins to automatically build Github repo on production server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, jenkins

I have successfully installed Jenkins and configured it with github using webhooks to invoke whenever a a commit is pushed. I have a react personal project which is hosted using Nginx and I want Jenkins to clone the repo and build it everytime a commit is pushed to the master branch. Would that be possible changing the root of the Jenkins or any other ways? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you have successfully configured  Jenkins with github. So when ever there is a commit Jenkins will do its job. What's issue exactly ??

Comment: @MyTwoCents : Thank you so much for replying. I figured it out anyways by hosting the project files in the Jenkins home directly itself by NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Wrote a small medium post on the same:
https://medium.com/@ssbannerjee/deploying-your-reactjs-app-on-your-domain-using-nginx-and-setting-up-jenkins-for-continuous-288e8d1bf90